# jQuery mobile "page" not loading when clicking link

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Basically my problem is that my data-role="page" in my jquery mobile website is not working when linked from a certain page, and does work when linked from another.

When it doesn't load when the html page is linked from a certain page, nothing happens when I click the link. **The url doesn't even change and stays like "page.html" instead of "page.html#anotherpage"**

Any ideas on this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!----------------------- PAGE 1 ------------------------------->

    <div id="view-profile-page" data-role="page">


        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
            <li class="ui-first-child">
                <a href="#edit-profile-page" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-edit">Go to page 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    <!------------------------ PAGE 2 ------------------------------>

    <div id="edit-profile-page" data-role="page">


        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div role="main">

            Page 2!

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery core -->
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
    <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some html/js code you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand the exact problem with your provided description. But here's my shot in the dark - scripts on a second JQM data-role="page" have certain restrictions because of the way JQM (hi)jax loads pages. Details here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Exactly, jQuery Mobile ignores everything at the 'head' region, except for the Title. So your scripts are not interfering

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark based on limited info you have provided, but have you validated your html? The kind of result you are seeing could happen if jQuery was confused by encountering invalid html, for example having two elements with the same ID.